# Animated panels like on Stackexchange Sites page

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

I would like to add a page to my website with a layout with animated panels that auto-slide around based on which one is clicked, as in Stackexchange's Sites page:
https://stackexchange.com/sites

What language and what specific methodology did the designers of Stackexchange use for laying out that page, or more meaningfully, what language and methodology would you recommend I research, in order to learn to create something similar? Perhaps there is a tutorial somewhere for creating something similar to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the sources of that page (achieved by activating the developer console in Chrome and looking at the [scripts panel](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts).) I can see they are making use of the [Isotope layout engine](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/).

Isotope is a jQuery plugin written in JavaScript and the site linked above contains some solid documentation; however if you are new to JavaScript then they may be a little difficult to follow.  A quick google brings up the following [Isotope tutorial](http://www.designlunatic.com/2011/08/isotope-tutorial/) which may help you get started.

Comment: Great! Thanks also for describing how to find this information in the future. BTW, is most of Stackexchange/Stackoverflow site also constructed using HTML5/jQuery then? (i.e., aside from the Q&A forum itself)